# SyntaxError: (irb):26: both block arg and actual block given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this query

```
= f.select(:city, Country.where(:country_code => "es").collect(&:cities) {|p| [ p.city, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Choose your city'})
```

Problem is I'm getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: (irb):26: both block arg and actual block given
```

From what I see I'm doing something wrong by including the `collect(&:cities)` and then declaring the block. Is there a way I can accomplish both with same query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Country.where(:country_code => "es").collect(&:cities)
```

is exactly the same as

```
Country.where(:country_code => "es").collect {|country| country.cities}
```

And this is why you are getting your error: you pass two blocks to the `collect` method. What you actually meant was probably something like this:

```
Country.where(:country_code => "es").collect(&:cities).flatten.collect {|p| [ p.city, p.id ] }
```

That will retrieve the countries, get the list of cities for each country, flattens the array to that you only have a one-dimensional one and the returns your array for the select.

As there is probably only one country per country code, you can also write it that way:

```
Country.where(:country_code => "es").first.cities.collect {|p| [ p.city, p.id ] }
```