# Rails - Block Arguments - flatten expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeblocks

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am getting this error message in relation to the method in this index:

```
 both block arg and actual block given
```

The method is:

```
<% Profile.try(:qualification).all.sort_by(&:profile.qualification.year_earned) do |qual| %>

        <div class="row">
              <% qual.each do |qualification| %>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="profilequalifications">
                        <%= @profile.try(:qualification).try(:title) %>
                    </div>  
                  </div>    
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="intpolmin">
                        <%= @profile.try(:qualification).try(:year_earned) %>: 
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="intpolmin">
                        <%= @profile.try(:qualification).try(:institution) %>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>  
                <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

I can see from this post:
[SyntaxError: (irb):26: both block arg and actual block given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288180/syntaxerror-irb26-both-block-arg-and-actual-block-given)

That I am using do |qual| and d0 |qualificaiton| which I think is the gist of the problem, but I can't figure out a solution. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: `qual.each do |qualification| ... end` is misplaced. Put the each after your sortBy in the same chain, then remove the second statement.

Comment: Thanks - that got it

Answer (score 0):

You should not use for cases enumeration both the `block` with `do...end` clause, and passed as an argument method's name to apply enumeration (in your case by value contained in `profile.qualification.year_earned`:

so choose between:

```
Profile.try(:qualification).all.sort_by(&:profile.qualification.year_earned)
```

and

```
Profile.try(:qualification).all.sort_by do |x| ... end
```